# Prose Equivalent to Poetic

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word equivalent to **poetic** for prose?

So instead of having a poetic license you would have a "prosetic" license??

Comment: I don't think it's what you're looking for in this context, but you might want to look up *prosody.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably want "prosaic" although it is generally used with its pejorative connotations:

http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/prosaic

> Having or using the style or diction of prose as opposed to poetry; lacking imaginativeness or originality

Comment: Great!  Strangely enough, even though "prosaic" is a great answer, your answer is not prosaic!

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Although "prosaic" is indeed the "prose equivalent" of "poetic," I don't think the phrase "prosaic license" is really what you're looking for unless you're trying to be sarcastic and imply that the person writing the prose is not taking enough *creative* license. (At least, that's how I'd interpret the phrase.)

Comment: @KyleStrand  YES...that is why I like **prosaic license** , a double-edged sword with a tiny twist of humor.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Well, in that case, perfect!

Answer (score 3):

Yes, several! A relevant Wikipedia entry on [Artistic License](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artistic_license).

> **Artistic License**
>
> Artistic license (also known as dramatic license, historical license, poetic license, narrative license, licentia poetica, or simply license)

Comment: I like narrative license.

Comment: Also "creative license."

Answer (score 2):

*prose* can be an adjective also.

a prose license

Comment: Yes, prose can be an adjective. No, it does not make sense in this context; it sounds like you've been officially licensed to write prose.